# How to get previous month from current month in java?

Tags: java, date, calendar, java-time, yearmonth

I have following scenario.

```
String currentMonth = SEP/2021
```

Here I want `String previous month = AUG/2021.`

How can I achieve this in java?

Comment: The code snippet wouldn't compile btw

Comment: You could have a Map of number string pairs and look them up.

Answer (score 7):

## *java.time*

You can use the `java.time` API to do it.

```
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                .appendPattern("MMM/uuuu")
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);

        String currentMonth = "SEP/2021";

        YearMonth currentYm = YearMonth.parse(currentMonth, dtf);
        YearMonth previousYm = currentYm.minusMonths(1);

        String previousMonth = previousYm.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(previousMonth);

        // If required, convert it into the UPPER CASE
        System.out.println(previousMonth.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Aug/2021
AUG/2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/o1G91I)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

```
    String currentMonth = "Sep/2021";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM/yyyy");
    YearMonth yearMonthCurrent = YearMonth.parse(currentMonth, formatter);
    YearMonth yearMonthPrevious = yearMonthCurrent.minusMonths(1);
    String previousMonth = formatter.format(yearMonthPrevious);
```

Comment: The input is `SEP/2021`, not `Sep/2021`.

Comment: What is the semantic difference between Sep and SEP ?

Comment: Well, a better question to yourself should have been: why did the Java architects decide to introduce `DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseCaseInsensitive` (you can check my answer for the demonstration)? Your code will fail for the input, `SEP/2021`, an input that might be coming as part of a response from some API or via some other input source (e.g. keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I gather from your question that your input and output both have the same format with month abbreviation in all upper case, which is non-standard. Of course we can handle it. I believe in putting an effort into some ground work so that when I get to the real work, I can do it in a simple way. In this case I am constructing a formatter for your format that I can then use both for parsing the input and formatting the output.

```
    Map<Long, String> monthAbbreviations = Arrays.stream(Month.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> Long.valueOf(m.getValue()),
                    m -> m.getDisplayName(
                                    TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH)
                            .toUpperCase()));
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, monthAbbreviations)
            .appendPattern("/u")
            .toFormatter();
    
    String currentMonthInput = "SEP/2021";

    YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.parse(currentMonthInput, monthFormatter);
    YearMonth previousMonth = currentMonth.minusMonths(1);
    String previousMonthOutput = previousMonth.format(monthFormatter);
    
    System.out.println(previousMonthOutput);
```

Output is the desired:

> AUG/2021

The two-arg `appendText` method of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` allows us to define our own texts for a field. In this case I use it for specifying our upper case month abbreviations. The method accepts a map from numbers to texts, so we need a map 1=JAN, 2=FEB, etc. I am constructing the map in a stream operation that starts from the values of the `Month` enum.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.